# Twitter bootstrap: Centered Thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of thumbnails. They have fixed size. I would like that the number of thumbnail in a row change with the width of the windows.

That's easy with Twitter Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesbourasseau/5WvAL/

The problem is, when the screen can accept like 4.5 Thumbnail, they are all align to the left and I get a gap on the right.

I would like to know if there is a possibility that the thumbnails stay centered, so the gap to the left and to the right, always stay the same...

Comment: Try making .thumbnail display:inline-block & Margin:0 auto;

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5WvAL/7/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply overwrite the `float:left` property on the thumbnail `li`s and set them to `display:inline-block` and then set `text-align:center` on the parent `ul`, like so:

**CSS**

```css
.thumbnails {
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbnails li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    float: none !important; /* to overwrite the default property on the bootstrap stylesheet */
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* ie7 support */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/5WvAL/21/

Comment: kinda works, but note this won't be exactly centred because of the left margin on spans