# Center a set of responsive thumbnails in a twitter-bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, thumbnails

I'm using twitter-bootstrap and need to create a carousel where each carousel group shows 5 thumbnails. The carousel needs to be centered on the page, with the images centered and no space between them. Also, the thumbnails should never take up more than one row. Instead, they should change they're size. I've cobbled together something based on: [Twitter Bootstrap 2 carousel - display a set of thumbnails at a time like jcarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745746/twitter-bootstrap-2-carousel-display-a-set-of-thumbnails-at-a-time-like-jcarou)  and [Twitter bootstrap: Centered Thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120186/twitter-bootstrap-centered-thumbnails) but am having trouble getting this to work. Thanks for any help. Here is the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/DeathRobot/shUT9/